# Is RTMP video flow displayable in a Aframe <a-videosphere> tag?

Tags: html, real-time, aframe, rtmp

I'm trying to realize real time (at least quick) streaming of 360° video flow.
To do that, I use the a-videosphere tag from aframe framework to render the 360° video inside a HTML page. 
The video flow is provided using rtmp services, I have a sever which offers a rtmp url to integrate inside my html page.

Actually, i'm able to display the rtmp flow inside a video tag using js scripts, now i would like to display it inside a videosphere, but it does not load the video tag.

I have learnt that rtmp is only displayable thanks to flash. Is that possible to integrate the video tag linked to the rtmp url inside the videosphere ?

Have a nice day and thank you for helping ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. Videos are possible in WebGL only due to HTML5, being able to write a video frame onto a canvas. Flash seems orthogonal to that. Need to use like m3u8

Comment: We have already realized that kind of streaming using HLS server and m3u8 playlists and we had a latency of 40 secs, with rtmp, we can't display 360 but we have a latency of 4 secs.